# postgres / postgis detecting new roads algorithm

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, buffer, intersect

I have a postgres (psql 9.1.22) database containing all the lines that ever existed in a region in OSM. I would like to detect newly mapped roads by year. This has to be done by a spatial query (because of how OSM works). The algorithm below is based on previous similar analysis in QGIS and FME. It works in theory. But I would like to hear if this way of approaching things is efficient in Postgres.

The idea is to get a collection of just the new roads for every year and use it for some stats (dump) and visuals (QGIS).

- Reproject to a local projection, so distances are in meters
- Extract valid roads at 1/1/2007 (year 0 for practical purposes) to  view timeslice0
- In timeslice0: calculate variable newlength = STLength (all roads were new). Copy timeslice0 to timeslicecollection
- Buffer timeslice0 by 7 meters
- Create timeslice1 with roads valid 1/1/2008
- Intersect timeslice1 on top of timeslice0, results to timeslice1intersect
- In timeslice1intersect, calculate length of pieces outside of buffers into variable newlength
- Aggregate newlength by osm_id (original line id) and pass the value on to timeslice1.
- Add timeslice1 to timeslicecollection
- Repeat for timeslice2 over timeslice1, till timeslice for 2017
- In timeslicecollection, compute newroad=1 if newlength>7 & newlength/length > 0.25
- In timeslicecollection, compute improvedroad=1 if newlength>7 & newlength/length =< 0.25

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Vince, see the last sentence of the first paragraph: "I would like to hear if this way of approaching things is efficient in Postgres."

Comment: This appears to be soliciting opinions on a hypothetical processing sequence. GIS SE uses a "Focused question / Best answer" model. As it stands, your Question doesn't contain a question, is quite broad, and any answers would be opinion-based. Please take the  [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for a better idea of how GIS SE is supposed to work. You might be able to start a discussion in our chat site, but it is underutilized, so you may not get much engagement.

Comment: Well, the question would be: "is this a silly approach or not?"
I understand if that's outside of scope of SE. Feel free to close this question.

Comment: OSM has history dumps. Why not use them to take a look at the actual data and history instead of "guessing"?

Comment: I have exactly those files in my postgres database, and I've worked with the data plenty. I just don't know enough postgres to know if my approach to this problem is silly or not. If you think it's worth just trying as outlined, than there's my answer. Not entirely silly.